# English translation needed for only 8 ahadith of Abu Hurairah that have no backup by a similar narration from any other sahabi in Hadith collections

Tags: hadith, sunni, uloom-al-hadith, sahaba, arabic-translation

I was reading a post here on this site regarding this topic.

[Are there narration chains for the coccyx/tailbone hadith that don't go through Abu Hurairah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35720/are-there-narration-chains-for-the-coccyx-tailbone-hadith-that-dont-go-through?rq=1)

The poster was kind enough to include the link however it's in Arabic.  I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find the English translation of these pages:

http://www.ibnamin.com/num_hadith.htm

https://www.alukah.net/library/0/72967/

Comment: This site is not a translation service.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant to ask if there's an English version of that article/discussion available online somewhere that I can directed to.